# WPF Image Cropping

Tags: c#, wpf, image, crop

I have a problem with image cropping. When I try to crop image with rectangle the cropping area is set to some strange value.
Here is xaml code:

```
   <Grid Name="GridImage">
        <Image Name="LoadedImage" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
        </Image>
        <Canvas  x:Name="ImageCanvas" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionRectangle" Stroke="LightBlue" Fill="#220000FF" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </Canvas>
  </Grid>
```

and here how I crop image:

```
            var imagePosition = LoadedImage.TransformToAncestor(GridImage).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
            Rect rect1 = new Rect(Math.Max(Canvas.GetLeft(SelectionRectangle) - imagePosition.X, 0), Math.Max(Canvas.GetTop(SelectionRectangle) - imagePosition.Y, 0), SelectionRectangle.Width, SelectionRectangle.Height);
            var ratioX = LoadedImage.Source.Width / LoadedImage.ActualWidth;
            var ratioY = LoadedImage.Source.Height / LoadedImage.ActualHeight;


            Int32Rect rcFrom = new Int32Rect
            {
                X = (int)(rect1.X * ratioX),
                Y = (int)(rect1.Y * ratioY),
                Width = (int)(rect1.Width * ratioX),
                Height = (int)(rect1.Height * ratioY)
            };
            try
            {
                BitmapSource bs = new CroppedBitmap((BitmapSource)LoadedImage.Source, rcFrom);
                LoadedImage.Source = bs;
                SetImageStretch(LoadedImage);
                SetElementVisibility(Visibility.Hidden, Visibility.Visible, SelectionRectangle);
            }


    private void SetImageStretch(Image image)
    {
        if (image.Source.Width > image.ActualWidth || image.Source.Height > image.ActualHeight)
            image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        else image.Stretch = Stretch.None;
    }
```

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Here how it looks before cropping:

[image]

How it looks after cropping:

[image]

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, it is impossible to know for sure what answer you need. Most likely, you should not be creating a new bitmap at all, and instead should be relying on transform options for the `Image` element to simply constrain how the original bitmap is presented on the screen. Please provide a good MCVE and explain _precisely_ what that code does now and what you want it to do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is with image resolution, e.g. 300 dpi, versus screen resolution (most likely 96 dpi). Have you checked image's PixelWidth and PixelHeight?

Comment: My PixelWidth = 1920, PixelHeight = 1080, dpiX = 72, dpiY = 72 and PixelFormat is BGR32.
But why using ratioX and ratioY doesn't do the correct cropping?

Comment: Do I need convert image to screen resolution or there is some other solution?
P.S. My application should process thousands of images and convert every to screen resolution will be very slow solution

Comment: Thanks. It helped.

Comment: @Anton You don't need to convert images, just recalculate the crop rectangle coordinates taking into account different screen and image DPI.