# Discrepency in WPF Image Cropping Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am  trying to develop an application that loads the image and crops it based on the rectangle defined by the user by using the mouse.
I am facing the same problem as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046987/wpf-image-cropping). The answer suggested to recalculate the coordinates of the cropping rectangle considering the difference between the Image DPI and the Screen DPI.

The xaml code is:

```
   <Grid Name="GridImage">
        <Image Name="LoadedImage" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
        </Image>
        <Canvas  x:Name="ImageCanvas" ClipToBounds="True"
                IsHitTestVisible="True" MouseLeftButtonDown="ImageCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="ImageCanvas_MouseMove"
                MouseUp="ImageCanvas_MouseUp"
                Background="Transparent">
            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionRectangle" Stroke="LightBlue" Fill="#220000FF" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </Canvas>
  </Grid>
```

The definition of the Canvas events are:

```
    private void ImageCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            isDrawing = true;
            startPoint = e.GetPosition(ImageCanvas);
            Canvas.SetLeft(SelectionRectangle, startPoint.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(SelectionRectangle, startPoint.Y);
            SelectionRectangle.Width = 0;
            SelectionRectangle.Height = 0;
            SelectionRectangle.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void ImageCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDrawing)
        {
            Point currentPoint = e.GetPosition(ImageCanvas);

            double width = Math.Abs(currentPoint.X - startPoint.X);
            double height = Math.Abs(currentPoint.Y - startPoint.Y);

            width = Math.Min(width, LoadedImage.ActualWidth - Canvas.GetLeft(SelectionRectangle));
            height = Math.Min(height, LoadedImage.ActualHeight - Canvas.GetTop(SelectionRectangle));

            SelectionRectangle.Width = width;
            SelectionRectangle.Height = height;
            Canvas.SetLeft(SelectionRectangle, Math.Min(startPoint.X, currentPoint.X));
            Canvas.SetTop(SelectionRectangle, Math.Min(startPoint.Y, currentPoint.Y));
        }
    }

    private void ImageCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ImageCanvas_MouseUp event triggered");
        isDrawing = false;
     
        CropImage();
    }
```

The code taken from the post is modified as follows:

```
 private void Crop()
 {
        var imagePosition = LoadedImage.TransformToAncestor(GridImage).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
   
        double imageDpiX = 96.0; 
        double imageDpiY = 96.0;
        Rect rect1 = new Rect(Math.Max(Canvas.GetLeft(SelectionRectangle) - imagePosition.X, 0), Math.Max(Canvas.GetTop(SelectionRectangle) - imagePosition.Y, 0), SelectionRectangle.Width, SelectionRectangle.Height);
        if (LoadedImage.Source is BitmapSource bitmapSource)
        {
            imageDpiX = bitmapSource.DpiX;
            imageDpiY = bitmapSource.DpiY;
        }
        
         //Set the screen DPI
        double screenDpiX = 96.0;
        double screenDpiY = 96.0;
        
        // Calculate the DPI ratios
        double ratioX = screenDpiX / imageDpiX;
        double ratioY = screenDpiY / imageDpiY;
        
        Int32Rect rcFrom = new Int32Rect
        {
            X = (int)(rect1.X * ratioX),
            Y = (int)(rect1.Y * ratioY),
            Width = (int)(rect1.Width * ratioX),
            Height = (int)(rect1.Height * ratioY)
        };
        
        try
        {
            BitmapSource bs = new CroppedBitmap((BitmapSource)LoadedImage.Source, rcFrom);
            LoadedImage.Source = bs;
            SetImageStretch(LoadedImage);
            SetElementVisibility(Visibility.Hidden, Visibility.Visible, SelectionRectangle);
        }
 }
```

Still the part of the image under the cropping rectangle is not reflected in the cropped image. The cropped image appears as a zoomed-in part of the original image. What am I misssing?

**EDIT**
Based on JonasH comments the following lines were added to `ImageCanvas_MouseUp` event:

```
Point mousePosition = e.GetPosition(LoadedImage);

double mouseX = mousePosition.X;
double mouseY = mousePosition.Y;
CropImage(mouseX, mouseY);
```

The rcFrom in CropImage method is computed as follows:

```
 var width = x - Canvas.GetLeft(SelectionRectangle);
 var height = y - Canvas.GetTop(SelectionRectangle);

    Int32Rect rcFrom = new Int32Rect
    {
        X = (int)x,
        Y = (int)y,
        Width = (int)width,
        Height = (int)height
    };
```

Here x and y correspond to (mouseX, mouseY)

After this modifcation no cropped image appears.

Comment: Can't you just use `MouseEventArgs.GetPosition(...)` with the image as the argument to get the mouse position in pixel coordinates?

Comment: JonasH, I updated the question

Comment: I have no idea what "no cropped image appears" mean in the context. Is the coordinates correct? Are you sure the code to apply the cropping works?. You should probably split the code that selects the rectangle, and the code that does the cropping, so you can test each independently.

Answer (score 0):

This is WPF. Therefore, we don't have to deal with dpi because WPFs rendering engine interprets pixels in a device independent manner (DIP). Dpi becomes only relevant if we do some real low-level rendering.

You can drastically simplify your code. All the arguments you need for a cropping function is the cropping area's bounding rectangle and of course the image source:

```cs
private void ImageCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  isDrawing = false;
     
  Geometry croppedAreaGeometry = this.SelectionRectangle.RenderedGeometry;
  Rect croppedAreaBounds = croppedAreaGeometry.Bounds;

  // Apply the canvas location to the bounding rectangle
  croppedAreaBounds.Offset(Canvas.GetLeft(this.SelectionRectangle), Canvas.GetTop(this.SelectionRectangle));  
    
  CropImage(this.LoadedImage, croppedAreaBounds);
  SaveImageToPng(this.LoadedImage.Source as BitmapSource, "croppedImage.png");  
}

private void CropImage(Image image, Rect cropBounds)
{
  var int32CropBounds = new Int32Rect((int)cropBounds.Left, (int)cropBounds.Top, (int)cropBounds.X, (int)cropBounds.Y);
  var croppedImageSource = new CroppedBitmap(this.Image.Source as BitmapSource, int32CropBounds);
  image.Source = croppedImageSource;
}

private void SaveImageToPng(BitmapSource croppedImageSource, string destinationPath)
{
  var imageFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(croppedImageSource);
  var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
  encoder.Frames.Add(imageFrame);

  using FileStream stream = File.Create(destinationPath);
  encoder.Save(stream);
}
```